# Help with CURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to code this in PHP:

```
curl -F 'access_token=123' \
 -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
```

But I have no idea how to do it...

Any ideas?

Thanks

TheBounder.

Comment: That's command-line curl syntax. PHP's interface is completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't execute curl like this, you must first install a PHP extension (cUrl) (look here for [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)).

Then you can do things like this:

```
$url="https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed";
$ch = curl_init();
$vars = "message=YourMessage";
if($ch === FALSE){
   echo "Errore init curl";
}else{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    $returned = curl_exec($ch);
    $returned = html_entity_decode($returned);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

I just copied some code that i used some time ago, take it as a starting point.

Comment: I added a missing `=`. In PHP it is generally best to either do `if(!$ch)` or `if($ch === FALSE)`

Comment: Yes, thanks, you are absolutely right, i'll update my own code too! :)

Comment: in the $vars how do I add more? So I want to pass message=test and access_token=test

Comment: `$vars = "message=YourMessage&acces_token=test";`